# Trying to get a trig calc working

Tags: java

i'm in high school and i'm just trying to program a trig calculator for my assignment, the problem is that i ran into a wall

here's the code (copy and pasted from net beans)

```
package trig.calc;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class TrigCalc {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int degs,sohcahtoa;
    double soh, cah, toa, rans = 0, num;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
    System.out.println("what do you want? Degrees(1) or Radians(2)");
     num = input.nextInt();
    String type;

    if (num == 1) {
        System.out.println("choose between 0-360");
        degs = input.nextInt();
        if (degs < 0 ) {
            return;
        } else if (degs > 360 ) {
          return;
        } else {
          System.out.println("choose Sin(1) Cos(2) Tan(3) ");
          sohcahtoa = input.nextInt();
          if (sohcahtoa > 3) {
             return;
        } else if (sohcahtoa < 0) {
            return;
        } else if (sohcahtoa == 1) {
           soh = num*180/Math.PI;
          System.out.println("The final answer is  " + Math.sin(soh));

        } else if (sohcahtoa == 2) {
            cah = num*180/Math.PI;
            System.out.println("the final answer is  " + Math.tan(cah));
        } else if (sohcahtoa == 3) {
            toa = num*180/Math.PI;
            System.out.println("the final answer is  " + Math.tan(toa));
        }   else if (num == 2) {
            System.out.println("choose a number between 1 and 2");
        }   else if (rans < 1) {
            System.out.println ("invalid input") ;
            return;
        } else if (rans > 2) {
            System.out.println ("invalid input") ;
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("choose between sin (1) cos (2) tan (3)");
            if (num == 1) {
                System.out.println("the final answer is  " + Math.sin(num));
        } 
    }     
}
}


}
}
```

for some reason when i choose radians it doesn't read the next part, i'm guessing its a bracket/indenting problem
any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: That's a lot of if statements but at a quick glance it looks like your option 2 if buried in the if statement for 1

Answer (score 0):

On inspection, your `else if num == 2` is INSIDE the `if num == 1` condition. Meaning it will never execute if you chose radians.